# how to "resubmit" drop-down selection with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use a headless browser ([Firefox Marionette](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/marionette/index.html)) to drive a drop-down selection process on a website I do not control. The setup is as follows: there's

- a drop-down menu where I can make a selection
- a second drop-down menu that reloads when I click my selection in the first one, exposing more options than it initially displays.

Clicking in a browser works fine, but if I try to do this in a console, the second menu does not reload:

```js
var sel1 = document.getElementById("1stmenu")
sel1.value="my selection"
sel1.selectedIndex=1
```

This changes the first drop-down menu appropriately, but does not trigger the 2nd menu's reload; the latter remains blank, displaying no options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This had (essentially) been asked before, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305766/how-to-remotely-simulate-a-dropdown-selection). [The first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14305906/11064961) worked for me: the drop-down menu is something like

```html
<select class="classname" id="idname" name="selname">
 <option value="" selected="selected">----- Choose -----</option>
 <option value="valuenamehere">Blah</option>
</select>
```

and what did the trick, after [making jQuery available in the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474354/include-jquery-in-the-javascript-console), was

```js
$('select[name="selname"]').val("valuenamehere").trigger('change');
```

---

**Edit:**

Even better: there's no need for `jQuery` at all, as documented in [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50587874/11064961) (also in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23612498/11064961) to a duplicate question). All I had to do was

```js
document.getElementsByName("selname")[0].value="valuenamehere"
document.getElementsByName("selname")[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))
```